# Allow ssh-keygen-wrapper to access "System Events" for all users in the same computer

Tags: applescript, permission, ssh

When I run my AppleScript in a remote mode, I get this message in an user where the script runs:

```
“sshd-keygen-wrapper“ wants access to control “System Events“. Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in “System Events“, and to perform actions within that app.
```

Is it possible to allow `ssh-keygen-wrapper` to access System Events" for all users in the same computer ONLY once, i.e. each new user in this computer doesn't need to allow this `ssh-keygen-wrapper` again?

It doesn't matter if it's a manual or programming solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should permit your AppleScript to access System Events from system preferences, 
`System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility`.

Click on the `+` icon under that panel and add your AppleScript.

If that not works, try adding it under `Full Disk Access` which you can select from the left pane.

[image: accessibility permissions list]

Comment: 1. You can't add apple script to Security & Privacy. 2. I added osascript and sshd-keygen-wrapper to Accessibility and to Full Disk Access. It doesn't work.